# Deserialized Rails ActiveRecord object won't save to SQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization, deserialization

Problem: After serializing and deserializing an object, a perfectly valid ActiveRecord model object will not save to SQL database.

The objects are serialized with:

```
File.open(output_file, 'wb+') { |f| f.write(YAML.dump(objects_to_marshal)) }
```

then deserialized with

```
stuff = YAML.load(File.read(output_file))
```

The object will not save, even if I explicitly set it's primary key ID and created_at, and updated_at fields to nil.

```
[64] pry(main)> fpt = stuff[10][0]
=> #<FakeProductTest:0x0055ee2244a938
 id: 1,
 name: "test",
 description: nil,
 created_at: Fri, 29 Dec 2017 21:24:07 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 18 Jan 2018 01:09:37 UTC +00:00>
[65] pry(main)> fpt.class.name
=> "FakeProductTest"
[66] pry(main)> FakeProductTest.count
=> 0
[67] pry(main)> fpt.save
=> true
[68] pry(main)> FakeProductTest.count
=> 0
[69] pry(main)>
```

I have verified via MySQL command line that I can read/write to the database, so it's not a permission issue.

Comment: try `FakeProductTest.reload` after saving and see if the count changes

Comment: [70] pry(main)> fpt.reload
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find FakeProductTest with 'id'=1

Comment: Doing something like this works for me. Something I often do when I see wierd behavior is `spring stop`, worth a shot.

Comment: I don't even have spring installed

Comment: is this code from tests or something?

Comment: no, it's not test code. I'm just illustrating the use-case I'm trying to accomplish. The above is my attempt to clearly explain what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Calling `var_name.dup.save` works.

Intermediate debugging steps that might be helpful:

```
[6] pry(main)> fpt.valid?
=> true
[7] pry(main)> fpt.changed?
=> false
[8] pry(main)> fpt.save!
=> true
[9] pry(main)> FakeProductTest.count
=> 0
[11] pry(main)> fpt.errors.messages
=> {}
```

Thanks to @thorncp